# Simultaneously updating functions dependent on each other

Tags: functions, function-construction, dynamic

I am new to using Mathematica and am grasping for understanding of structures equivalent to looping constructs in other languages. Suppose I have 2 functions that depend upon each other and I need to update them sequentially once I initialize one of the functions; An example is provided below; The 2 related functions are 'a' and 'g'. In the initial instance, 'a' gets computed using the value a0, but for the subsequent iterations, it is a function of the latest value of 'g' (say = g).

```
a = 1;(*In subsequent iterations, a = g from FoldList*)
g[x_,y_]:=x+a y;

FoldList[g,1,{1,2,3,4}]

Out[300]= {1,2,4,7,11}
```

The correct output I want to obtain is {1,2,6,24,120}.
Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't `FoldList[Plus, 1, {1, 2, 3, 4}]` do exactly this? No need to add a new function – just use addition, in the sense of `g[x_, y_] = x + y` and then `FoldList[g, 1, {1, 2, 3, 4}]`.

Comment: Thanks for the Response @Roman. FoldList would evaluate to give {1,g(1,1)=2,g(g(1,1),2=4),...} without updating the value of a to g(1,1) for the next iteration. As I mentioned, I want 'a' to get updated as well. I tried setting a delayed assignment with a := g, only to get a set delayed error.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What are you trying to achieve? Why do you care that `a` is updated *during* the iteration? Mathematica is very different from other programming languages and the quicker you can leave looping constructs behind, the easier you'll learn it.

Comment: You need to define `g` as `g[x_, y_] := a = x + a y` or `g = (a = # + a #2) &`

Comment: Thanks Coolwater. If I understand correctly, this is similar to a recursion problem, like the Fibonacci sequence and your solution seems to point to the same. My bad in not reducing the problem correctly.